# Print attribute value based on condition attribute in same element (XML Python)

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file like this:

```
<button_map>
<button id="abs_axis_11" label="">
      <device type="keyboard" id="0" name=""/>
      <event type="button" id="g"/>
</button>
<button id="abs_axis_16" label="Melee">
      <device type="keyboard" id="0" name=""/>
      <event type="button" id="v"/>
/button>
<button id="abs_axis_11" label="">
      <device type="joystick" id="0" name="Controller"/>
      <event type="button" id="9"/>
</button>
</button_map>
```

The condition is if button id = "abs_axis_11" && name = "" : print output = g, but I don't find a way to remove id = 9 in result output (using Python)

My working code:

```
for event in root.findall('/button_map/button[@id="abs_axis_11"][device[@name=""]]/event'):
    button = event.get('id')
    print button
```

Comment: Can you provide your work-in-progress code?

Comment: Also, what attribute value are you trying to print? `event/@id`?

Comment: @DanielHaley yes, I want to do that

Comment: @chuckx: My working code, I can't find way to set condition to button/device
    for event in root.findall('./button_map/button[@id="abs_axis_11"/event'):
    button = event.get('id')
    print button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take some liberty with the example below, as the data and code you provided isn't a complete, working example (for future reference, [try following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Assumptions:

- you're using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module
- the XML snippet you provided is a subset of the overall message you're parsing

Based on those assumptions I put together the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML_DATA = """
<root>
  <button_map>
    <button id="abs_axis_11" label="">
      <device type="keyboard" id="0" name=""/>
      <event type="button" id="g"/>
    </button>
    <button id="abs_axis_16" label="Melee">
      <device type="keyboard" id="0" name=""/>
      <event type="button" id="v"/>
    </button>
    <button id="abs_axis_11" label="">
      <device type="joystick" id="0" name="Controller"/>
      <event type="button" id="9"/>
    </button>
  </button_map>
</root>
"""

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(XML_DATA))
for event in tree.findall(
    './button_map/button[@id="abs_axis_11"]/device[@name=""]/../event'):
  print "Result: %s" % (event)
  print "Event ID: %s" % event.get('id')
```

The output of this script is:

```
$ python python-xml.py
Result: <Element 'event' at 0x7efd53f8c610>
Event ID: g
```

Here's are some pointers regarding your XPath query:

- `device` is a child element not an attribute of `button`. Therefore I removed 
  it from the brackets (which was causing an `invalid predicate` error for me,
  and specified it an element in the hierarchy
- because of the above, I used `..` to navigate to parent element of `device` 
  (i.e. `button`) and then down to it's child element `event`

Comment: thank you very much, it works now. For the first time I was also get that error "invalid predicate" too. I think I get it now. Thanks again.